# How to handle path operations getting mixed-up in FastAPI?

Tags: python, fastapi

I've got two path operation functions that look similar, except that the first one returns all the data for a *specific* user and the second one only the data of the *current* (logged in) user (with the schema `UserOut`, which has fewer fields):

```
@router.get("/{id}", response_model=User)
async def get_user(user_id: PydanticObjectId):
    user = await User.find_one(User.id == user_id)
    if user is None:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=404, detail="User not found")
    return user


@router.get("/me")
async def get_current_user(current_user: User = Depends(get_current_active_user)):
    return current_user
```

The problem is when I call from Postman the second method, it takes the endpoint `/me` as the `id` of the first endpoint, so I always get the pydantic validation error that `"me" is not a valid user ID`.

How could I solve this problem? Do I need to necessarily modify my endpoints or are there any other alternatives?

Comment: How about /user?id=XXX

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can solve this quite easily by switching places of the two path operation functions (i.e.,  declare `/me` before `/{id}`):

```py
@router.get("/me")
async def get_current_user():
    pass
    
@router.get("/{id}")
async def get_user():
    pass
```

Because [path operations are evaluated in order](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/path-params/#order-matters), this makes sure that endpoint `/me` (which is a fixed path and can be used to get data about the current user) is evaluated first, and if there is not a match, the endpoint `/{id}` is then evaluated (which is used to get data about a specific user by some user ID).

Answer (score 2):

The fact that both endpoints return the same resource (they both return a user) is an indicator that maybe they should just be 1 endpoint that returns a user specified by an ID, or the current logged-in one *by default*.

While you *can* differentiate based on how the endpoints are defined ([as given by the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73254762/2745495)), I find that solution to be "brittle", in the sense that you (and other developers maintaining and reading your code) would have to *always* remember that the order matters, which can easily cause bugs when you (or someone else) reorganize or refactor the code.

So, as an alternative, you can just combine those 2 endpoints into 1 `get_user` endpoint:

```
from typing import Optional
from fastapi import Query
from pydantic import BaseModel, NonNegativeInt

class User(BaseModel):
    user_id: NonNegativeInt
    other_field: str = ""

    @classmethod
    async def find_one(cls, user_id: NonNegativeInt) -> "User":
        """This is a fake method that returns a User from somewhere"""
        return cls(user_id=user_id, other_field=str(user_id) * 5)

def get_current_active_user() -> User:
    """This is a fake method that somehow gets the logged-in user"""
    return User(user_id=0, other_field="This is the logged-in user")

@router.get("/user", response_model=User)
async def get_user(user_id: Optional[NonNegativeInt] = Query(default=None)):
    if user_id:
        user = await User.find_one(user_id)
    else:
        user = get_current_active_user()

    if not user:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=404, detail="User not found")

    return user
```

```
$ curl -XGET localhost:8000/user
{"user_id":0,"other_field":"This is the logged-in user"}

$ curl -XGET localhost:8000/user?user_id=444
{"user_id":444,"other_field":"This is a different user"}
```

The advantages of this are, for one, the order *doesn't anymore matter*, and two, the same set of validations and parameters on the request and the response can be done on the same endpoint function.

Now for the case of having 2 different response models:

> ... the first one returns all the data for a specific user and the second one only the data of the current (logged in) user (with the schema UserOut, which has less fields)

I don't know the use-case why the response for the logged-in user needs to have less fields, but, check out the section on [defining multiple models](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/extra-models/#multiple-models) from the FastAPI tutorials. Basically, you would want a base user model that has the minimum fields (to represent your logged-in user) and a more specific user model with all the other fields to represent the "found" users) Then define your route to be a [`Union` of these 2 different types](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/extra-models/#union-or-anyof).

```
class BaseUser(BaseModel):
    user_id: NonNegativeInt

class LoggedInUser(BaseUser):
    pass

class SomeOtherUser(BaseUser):
    other_field: str

    @classmethod
    async def find_one(cls, user_id: NonNegativeInt) -> "SomeOtherUser":
        """This is a fake method that returns a User from somewhere"""
        return cls(user_id=user_id, other_field="This is a different user")

def get_current_active_user() -> LoggedInUser:
    """This is a fake method that somehow gets the logged-in user"""
    return LoggedInUser(user_id=0)

@router.get("/user", response_model=Union[SomeOtherUser, LoggedInUser])
async def get_user(user_id: Optional[NonNegativeInt] = Query(default=None)):
    if user_id:
        user = await SomeOtherUser.find_one(user_id)
    else:
        user = get_current_active_user()

    if not user:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=404, detail="User not found")

    return user
```

```
$ curl -XGET localhost:8000/user
{"user_id":0}

$ curl -XGET localhost:8000/user?user_id=444
{"user_id":444,"other_field":"This is a different user"}
```